# What does it mean when a letter has both superscript and subscript?

Tags: notation, finance

I have a formula for Bond Valuation of a Level Coupon Bond, but  I don't understand the notation. It looks like:

It's the bottom formula in the image below, starting with PV =

[image]

What does it mean when the A has both T and R next to it?

Comment: The T means $A_R$ to the T-th power.  The R is an index.  It means that somehow the value of $A_R$ was determined or related in some way to R.  $A_R$ is just a variable.  $A_R^T$ is just a variable raised to the T-th power.

Comment: Okay. So you calculate it based on A? Like if A is, 5, and T is 2, it's just 25? Sorry for my inexpertise, I don't study finance.

Comment: Just based on what's being computed here, I'd have said $A_R^T$ was the present value of a stream of $T$ periodic payments of $1$ euro (sorry, can't figure out how to make the euro symbol) discounted at $R$.

Comment: I've changed my mind.  I think that it's a way of notating that the value A is determined by R and T so depending on what R is and what T is you have a value $A_{R,T}$ and $A_R^T$ is another (ambiguous) way of writing that.

$A_R^T = 1/(1+R) + 1/(1+R)^2 + ..... + 1/(1+R)^T$.  You can think of this in two equivalent ways: A is a function of R and T: or there is a 2-dim grid of values (a matrix) and $A_R^T$ is the entry in the Rth column and the Tth row.  Or I could still be wrong.

Comment: Could you zoom out so we can see the whole equation above it?

Comment: My first that was that A_1 = 5, and A_2 = 7, and A_3 = 4 so if T = 2 then $A_2^2 = 49$ or $A_3^2 = 16$.  But I don't think so any more.  I now think $A_R^T = f(R, T) = 1/(1 + R) + .... + 1/(1 + R)^T$ So $A_3^2 = 1/(1 + 3) + 1/(1+ 3)^2 = 1/4 + 1/16 = 5/16$.  But that's my educated interpretation.  I might be wrong.

Comment: Notation seems weird.  Notice the whole equation is for "PV" which to my mathematical mind looks like "P times V" but that is obviously not that case because the RHS of the equation is obviously not a product.  To my mathematical mind $A_R^T$ looks like you have a series $A_i = \{A_1, A_2,....\}$ and this is $(A_R)^T$ but if you look at the equation above that is obviously not the case either.  By above I'd say to my mathematical mind that we have $A = f(R,T)$ a two variable function but it's clear financiers do not have mathematical minds nor vice versa.

Comment: I've edited the picture so it's more clear. Hope this resolves the debate..?

Comment: Yeah,  I think they are simply introducing shorthand.  "$A_R^T = \frac 1 {1 + R} + .... + \frac 1 {(1 + R)^T}$".

Answer (score 2):

In the context it is clear that $A_R^T = \frac 1{1 + R} + \frac 1{(1+R)^2}+ ...\frac 1{(1+R)^T}$.

Which by geometric series = $\frac {1-(1+R)^{T+1}}{R}$

So I think in this case it is simply a double index.  There are two values that determine $A$; they are $R$ and $T$ so we need two indexes to reference $A$.  We could have used $A_{R,T}$ just as easily.

In my opinion, I'd have chosen $A_{R,T}$ notation as $A_R^T$ looks like $(A_R)^T$ which I first thought it was (and it still might turn out to be) in my comment.

Comment: So to repeat.  I don't *know* what the answer is but I *think* this is the meaning...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on context, but in this case I think $R$ is an index (i.e., part of the name of the variable) and $T$ is an exponent.

Comment: That's what I that at first too, but if you look at the text $A_R^T$ is equal to a sum of a geometric series.  I now think it is simply a double index.

Comment: That is *very* silly notation but I am afraid you may be right.

Comment: It's a silly notation to mathematicians (because it looks like something else) but perhaps to financiers they consider it a form of matrix notation.  Lot at their notation for the variable "PV"... well, it's obviously not a product!  Different conventions for different disciplines, I guess.

Comment: Sectarianism aside it's a silly notation mainly because it implies two different incompatible meanings for the same symbol (superscript $T$) in one line.

Comment: I agree.  Ambiguity is to be avoided in symbols.  But I can't say I've never seen that notation before.  It's more common in older books or in books were it's clearer by context or choice of symbol that it probably isn't exponetiation.  In this case as they used $(c/(1 + R)^T$ it's clear that superscript $T$ *can* mean and has been used to mean exponentiation *in the previous !line!* so they really shouldn't have used it.  I'd say it's "bad" rather than "silly".

Comment: I *almost* wonder if the authors thought that $\sum_{i = 1}^T \frac 1{(1 + R)^i}$ does equal $x^T$ for some $x$ which is notated as $A_R$.  It doesn't, of course.  But I doubt the authors can be that mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Let there be $A_1,A_2,A_3...$

And their squares are: $(A_1)^2,(A_2)^2,(A_3)^2...$

We don't need the parantheses:
$A_1^2,A_2^2,A_3^2...$

Do you understand now?

$$\large A_b^c = (A_b)^c$$

---

Do you know the quadratic formula?

> Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ roots of $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$
>
> Sum of squares of the roots ($x_1^2+x_2^2$) is equal to $(\frac{-b}{a})^2-\frac{2c}{a}$